# Google Apps Script returning wrong minute from Date object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script I am directly inputting the arguments into a Date object constructor and the returned date is incorrect for the minutes and seconds. The returned minutes and seconds are consistent, i.e., it always returns the same incorrect numbers when given the same input. Also, the output changes for different inputs.

Has anybody seen this before or have any debugging tips to isolate the problem?

[image: Screenshot of direct date assignment (green arrow is code and red arrow is debug log)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are given time parameter as
     `19hr 2min 53sec 948671msec`

and  `1second` = `1000 millisecond`

when you convert the above milliseconds to standard time it is

`948671 millisecond` = `15min 48sec 671millisecond` 
when you add this millisecond parameter to your time parameter
it would be,

```
         19hr   2min  53sec
      +   0hr  15min  48sec  671millisecond
     -----------------------------------------
         19hr  18min  41sec  671millisecond
     -----------------------------------------
```

google app script will automatically sort the time constraint. thats why you get different time in input and output of script.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the milliseconds and the issue was fixed. I'm not sure why the Date object acts weirdly when given milliseconds.